# Releasing view object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, dealloc

Just wondering why I'm getting the 'baseView' undeclared error in dealloc when building this.

```
CGRect baseFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:baseFrame];
self.view = baseView;

- (void)dealloc {
[baseView release];
[super dealloc];
```

}

I created the view with an alloc, I'm not sure why I'm getting the error when trying to release baseView. (I get the same error when trying to set it to nil in viewDidUnload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "baseView" is not declared in the .h file would be my guess. The pointer only exists for the life cycle of the method in which it's declared.

You can fix this as follows:

```
CGRect baseFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:baseFrame];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
[baseView release];
```

The view will retain the baseView, so you can go ahead and release it here. Then remove the reference in `dealloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The `baseView` pointer is declared locally in whatever method you are creating it in. If you need to play around with `baseView` in other methods too, I suggest you add it as an instance variable.

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass {
    UIView *baseView; // declare as an instance variable;
}

@end

// MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (void)someMethod {
    baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:..];
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
    // baseView is accessible here
}

- (void)yetAnotherMethod {
    // baseView is accessible here too
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use with

```
[self.view addSubView:baseView];
[baseView release];
```

If you want to release from dealloc , you need to declare in .h file

Answer (score 0):

`baseView` is declared as a local variable and is known or can be accessed only by the method in which it is declared. If it has to be accessed by other methods of the class make sure `baseView` is declared as an instance variable.

Comment: In this case that method was 'viewDidLoad'. So it would be considered local to that method only then correct?

Comment: Yes exactly so it cant be accessed in dealloc